# HTML/CSS Table columns fixed on page and others are always outside screen with scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question about a html table, I know a windows application that has this, a vertical scrollable table, but some columns are fixed on the page and others are always outside the page. I have a example:

- The black border is the page, which is responsive.
- The red border is the table.
- The green border is the part that is always fullscreen on the page,
  always with The same columns.
- The blue border is the part that's always off the screen with
  information that's not required but if you need it you can scroll to
  the right.

[image: Table example]

Anyone have an idea how to do this? In CSS? Or do I need JavaScript for it?

My current code:
This class is attached to the  tag.

```
/*MAIN TABLE*/
.tableMain {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

But I think I need 2 classes, 1 on page class, and 1 off page class so I can define the columns that should be outside the page. But I really don't know how to do that. Currently I've edited my headercells with this idea.

```
.tableCell, .tableHeaderCell{
    width: 8.5%;
}

.tableSecondCell{
    width: 150px;
}
```

This is my current HTML:

```
<table class='tableMain'>
    <thead class='tableHeader'>
        <tr class='tableHeaderRow'>
            <th class='tableCell'>Name</th>
            <th class='tableCell'>Email</th>
            <th class='tableCell'>Role</th>
            <th class='tableCell'>Username</th>
            <th class='tableCell'>Department</th>
            <th class='tableSecondCell'>Team</th>
            <th class='tableSecondCell'>Web</th>
            <th class='tableSecondCell'>App</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class='tableBody'>
        <tr class='tableRow'>
            <td class='tableCell'>User Name</td>
            <td class='tableCell'>username1@example.com</td>
            <td class='tableCell'>employee</td>
            <td class='tableCell'>username1</td>
            <td class='tableCell'>Support</td>
            <td class='tableSecondCell'>Team1</td>
            <td class='tableSecondCell'>True</td>
            <td class='tableSecondCell'>True</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should always attach your code which you tried

Comment: I've added my code @Sonia

Comment: The HTML  code? ?

Comment: Its generated in php, but i will get an example

Comment: Added html @Sonia

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead below css for the table to scroll

```
.tableMain {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

and wrap a div .table-responsive around table tag

```
.table-responsive {
    min-height: .01%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: Now the table is fullscreen of the page, but what i need, it that the colums "Name, Email, Role, Username, Department" are sticky on the page, and the others (Team,Web,App) should be always off screen, with vertical scroll to it.

Comment: I need something like 2 tbody's, 1 thats ALWAYS on the screen and the other ALWAYS off the screen